# Que retorna then exactamente? JS

Tags: javascript, promesas

La pregunta se relaciona con el uso de promesas en `js`, pues bien, se supone que usamos el método `then` para definir el `resolve` del *callback* que le pasamos al constructor `Promise` y `catch` para definir el `reject` ...

```
'use strict';
let promesa = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => { 
  const result = true;
  if (result){
    resolve();
  } else {
    reject();
  }
});

promesa
  .then( () => { 
    console.log("Exito !");
  })
  .catch( () => {
    console.log("Fracaso !");
  })
```

Pues bien, a la hora de usar `catch`, estamos empleando la promesa que `then` retorna, sin embargo esa promesa no es igual a la variable `promesa` ...

```
 'use strict';
let promesa = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => { 
  const result = true;
  if (result){
    resolve();
  } else {
    reject();
  }
});

let new_promesa = promesa.then( () => { 
    console.log("Exito !");
  })
console.log((new_promesa === promesa) ? "Las promesas son iguales!" : "Las promesas son diferentes!");
new_promesa.catch( () => {
    console.log("Fracaso !");
  })
```

Salida:

```
Las promesas son diferentes!
Exito !
```

Exactamente cual es la promesa que retorna `then` y por debe ser diferente a la primera promesa?

Answer (score 2):

En respuesta a:

> cual es la promesa que retorna `then`?

El método `then` retorna **una nueva promesa** que, dependiendo del resultado después de la invocación de la función de control, pueden darse diferentes casos:

- Si se recibe un valor, la Promesa devuelta por el método `then` queda resuelta adoptando el valor de retorno.
- Si se produce un error, la Promesa devuelta por el método `then es rechazada, adoptando el error como su valor.
- Si se devuelve una Promesa ya resuelta, la Promesa devuelta por el método `then` queda resuelta adoptando el valor de la promesa anterior.
- Si se devuelve una Promesa con un objeto pendiente de resolver, la resolución o rechazo devueltos por `then` quedará a esperas de que la Promesa establecida para la función de control quede resuelta. Además, el valor de la Promesa en estado pendiente será el mismo que el valor devuelto por el controlador.

**Fuente**: [Promise.then > Valor de retorno](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#valor_de_retorno)

---

En respuesta a:

> por debe ser diferente a la primera promesa?

Para permitir [encadenamiento](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#encadenamiento), el método devuelve una `Promise`.

Comment: A que te refieres con la "funcion de control"?

Comment: Se refiere a la función que resuelve o rechaza la promesa.